# "Match has been delayed/postponed for two days"."He has been jailed/punished for two years"

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect, past-participles

"Match has been delayed/postponed for two days"."He has been jailed/punished for two years"

I need to ask whether "subject+has been+past participle+for two years" reflects the  last past years as in since last two years or next two years?

Somehow i am also thinking that these sentences may reflect the complete action ( in sense of past) which had the duration of two years as in "match has already been delayed for two days"

Answer (score 1):

*The match has been postponed for two days* means that a decision has been taken to play it two days from now instead of today. We could also say it during those two days.

*He has been jailed for two years* means that he has been sentenced to two years in prison (*punished* is not appropriate here). We could also say it during those two years.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks. I suppose i almost understood. Kindly correct me on this pls. If i say "Room has been painted for two days" it does not refer that "painting" will get done in two days time/two days from now but "Period of two days" which already happened as in past.(But otherway around for postoned and jailed )

Comment: What you wrote earlier make sense but do you not think "If i say "Match has been postponed for two years/He has been jailed for two years" may also depict the actions which already happened ealier/before as in "Match has been postponed for two years/He has been jailed for two years (refering previously occurences as in 2010, and those actions had duration of two years)

Comment: or do i precisly have to add "before" with those sentences to make them clear that occurences already happened in past?

Comment: What you must realise is that _for_ has different meanings with certain verbs. _Postpone for [time]_ means 'delay the date on which something happens'. _Jail for [time]_ means 'sentence to that much time in prison'. If the jail sentence started in 2010, we would say "He _was jailed_ for two years in 2010."

Comment: "Room has been painted for two days" is not idiomatic English. Firstly, it should be '**the** room'. Secondly, we would say 'The room was painted two days ago.' A better example would be 'My sister has been ill for two days'. This is another meaning of _for_.

Comment: if "The room has been painted for two days" should be interpreted or written as "The room was painted two days ago" then could "my earlier examples of "Match has been postponed for two years/He has been jailed for two years" also be interpreted as (Match was postponed two years ago/He was jailed two years ago)  and if not then how would I as a non-native english speaker figure out the different usage of "for" in my given examples for "painted" "postponed" and "jailed"?

Comment: The normal meaning of "The match has been postponed for (X amount of time)" is that it should have taken place today, or very recently, but now won't happen until that amount of time has elapsed. It's unlikely anyone would interpret it as 'It was postponed two years ago and still hasn't happened'.

Comment: We would say "He has been _in jail_ for two years".

Comment: .Thank you for making me uderstand my each query.